# Extract <td> value using regexp or xpath from an html which contains a certain text

Tags: java, regex, xpath, jmeter

I am using JMeter and I want to extract from a response the value of a column from a row which contains a certain value :

Concretely I want to get the row which contains  **677777** and for that row to get the column
**dv-col dv-col-type-enum dv-col-task-state** which in this specific case is **Open**.

Tried several regexps but no success yet,so any help or clue is welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body class="bootstrap env-dlt">
        <div id="main-container" class="container-fluid">
            <div id="main-header" class="header"></div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="dv-filters large-content"></div>
                <div class="dv-container large-content">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody class="taskList">
                            <tr>..</tr>
                            <tr>..</tr>
                            <tr>..</tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-string dv-col-task-panel"></td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-string dv-col-task-phase"></td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-long dv-col-task-proposal_reference">
                                    <a href="/presentation/workflow/tasks/111111/detail.html">
                                        677777
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-long dv-col-task-proposal_acronym"></td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-enum dv-col-task-state">
                                    Open
                                </td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-long dv-col-task-owner"></td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-date dv-col-task-deadline"></td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-double dv-col-task-score"></td>
                                <td class="dv-col dv-col-type-action"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>..</tr>
                            <tr>..</tr>
                            <tr>..</tr>
```

Xpath might be an alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: You should use xpath. Parsing HTML with regex is always a headache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: did not know about that thread, however my feeling was as well that is more suitable for xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the xpath for getting the desire result is:

```
//tr[td/a[contains(text(),"677777")]]/td[@class="dv-col dv-col-type-enum dv-col-task-state"]/text()
```

first find the `<tr>` that contains a `<td>` which has an `<a>`'s text() contains, or equal to 677777, then find the `<td>` tab which `class` is "dv-col dv-col-type-enum dv-col-task-state" under the target `<tr>`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get the row which contains 677777

Using XPath (selects the entire row node):

```
//tr[*=677777]
```

To get the column data testing for the contents of the `@class`attribute:

```
//tr[*=677777]/td[@class[contains(.,"dv-col-task-state") and contains(.,"dv-col-type-enum") ]]
```

(Assuming you don't have or don't care about matching classes which include those class names. Ex: `dv-col-task-state-something`. If that's a concern, you need to concatenate and match the white-space in the class attribute to assure they represent individual class names)

Comment: Both answer were correct I validated the first one , for this one a big +1